# Office 365 - from VS'13 and Windows 7

Tags: office365

I would like to pull some messages off of our Office 365 server.

I read a bit about using the REST API

The only example VS code remotely close to my use case that I have found in all the documentation is the following:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Win-Snippets

However, when I try to open this project, It says I must have Windows 8. Is there any reference code I can use for the most simple case of connecting to Office 365 outlook and retrieving a message, without being on windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I need the exact thing myself.

Unfortunately Msdn forums says it is not possible, because the user have to do the authentication in every login. Check this out:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef978452-25c0-46df-8891-69368358b6b4/calling-office365-mvc-sample-from-windows-service?forum=appsforoffice